# Make redirection in express post, by react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am using react and its router to make the redirect of my application. When I use a get instruction in my server express it works fine. But when I make a post instruction, it doesn't redirect. What I have to do?. Here is my code:

(I receive the response in the way that I expect, but after that, nothing happens)

```
lisaApp.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
  const validationResult = validateSignupForm(req.body);
  if (!validationResult.success) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      success: false,
      message: validationResult.message,
      errors: validationResult.errors
    });
  }

  var newClient = req.body
  newClient.clientemailname = newClient.userclient
  newClient.client_id = uuid.v4()

  delete newClient.confirmPassword

  ClientApi.saveClient(newClient, function (err, usr) {
    if (err) return res.status(500).send(err.message)

    console.log('ready to redirect') //Here, the response has a status "0k"
    res.redirect('/')
  });
});
```

Comment: r u using react router, if yes then which version ?

Comment: Yes, I am using "react-router-dom", version: "^4.0.0-beta.8"

Comment: I think is the last version

Comment: I think this will still works with v4 `import {browserHistory} from 'react-router';` and `browserHistory.push('/')`

Comment: If you are inside a component you can also use `MyComponent.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object
};` and `this.context.router.push('/');`

Comment: I think, you can still use your `/signup` endpoint to get `redirectUrl` from json value and in turn can be used in react side to redirect.

Comment: @oliv37, no it doesn't work, it says to me browserHistory is not defined. :(

Comment: @Tolsee can you explain me in more detail. In advance, thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write your api like this:

```
    lisaApp.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
      const validationResult = validateSignupForm(req.body);
      if (!validationResult.success) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          success: false,
          message: validationResult.message,
          errors: validationResult.errors
        });
      }

      var newClient = req.body
      newClient.clientemailname = newClient.userclient
      newClient.client_id = uuid.v4()

      delete newClient.confirmPassword

      ClientApi.saveClient(newClient, function (err, usr) {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send(err.message)

        console.log('ready to redirect') //Here, the response has a status "0k"
        return res.status(200).json({
            success:true,
            redirectUrl: '/'
        })
      });
    });
```

And in your React file you can use this code in your POST handler to redirect using react-router.

`this.history.pushState(null, res.redirectUrl);`

Comment: First, thanks a lot for your help. But, when I put "this.history.pushState(null, res.redirectUrl);" The browser shows me the next error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at app.js:18956. Maybe is because I am using the las version of the react router (react-router-dom). Maybe?

Comment: I use window.location.href = '/'; Is correct?. Because this doesn't use the react-router-dom.

Comment: Yeah, I think, that is also doable.

Comment: Thanks, you help me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

By MSDN redirect for POST and PUT method has status 303: `res.status(303)`